# Нужно скрыть или (зашифровать ) ссылку , чтобы после декомпиляции её не было видно

Tags: java, android

```
editor.putString("Url", "https://drive.google.com/.....");
editor.apply();
```

В build.gradle прописать
minifyEnabled true
не помогает !

Answer (score 1):

Не существует способа на 100% спрятать что-то в исходном коде, и шифрование вам ничем не поможет, если ваше приложение должно использовать данную ссылку, то вы должны будете предусмотреть способ расшифровки, а значит просмотрев код можно будет получить ее. Единственное, что можно сделать, это не использовать чувствительные данные в коде который может оказаться у пользователя, например создав прослойку в виде веб-сервиса, который бы по определённому урлу отдавал бы данные из вашего приватного хранилища. И раз у пользователей нет доступа напрямую к данным, и к коду сервиса прослойки они не получат вашу ссылки (ну если забыть о взломе сервиса и возможных ошибках в коде).